# Android GridLayout design

Tags: android, grid-layout

Firstly, I  thank you all for your help.

So my problem is usually simple, but I can not find the error.

I want to have this form:

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4XLp.jpg)

As against this interface is intended for the tablet so I want the same interface in table 7.0 inches and 10.1 inches with the same size of the layout except for the main layout in the middle there will be the size of four layout

but with my current code I receive this form:

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDM0h.jpg)

and here is my current code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:rowCount="4" >
      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="242dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_column="0"
          android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
          android:layout_row="0"
          android:background="@drawable/aze"
          android:padding="2dp" >
    </LinearLayout>
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
          android:layout_row="0"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="2" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="181dp"
            android:layout_height="71dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:text="Button" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:text="Button" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:text="Button" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button15"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:text="Button" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button16"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:text="Button" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button17"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </GridLayout>
      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_column="3"
          android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
          android:layout_row="0"
          android:background="@drawable/c"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:padding="2dp"
          android:paddingBottom="2dp"
          android:paddingLeft="2dp"
          android:paddingRight="2dp"
          android:paddingTop="2dp" >
    </LinearLayout>
       <CalendarView
           android:id="@+id/calendarView1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="141dp"
           android:layout_column="0"
           android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
           android:layout_margin="2dp"
           android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
           android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
           android:layout_row="1"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:padding="2dp"
           android:paddingBottom="2dp"
           android:paddingLeft="2dp"
           android:paddingRight="2dp"
           android:paddingTop="2dp" />
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="550dp"
       android:layout_height="265dp"
       android:layout_column="1"
       android:layout_columnSpan="2"
       android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
       android:layout_margin="2dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
       android:layout_row="1"
       android:layout_rowSpan="2"
       android:background="@drawable/pp"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:padding="2dp"
       android:paddingBottom="2dp"
       android:paddingLeft="2dp"
       android:paddingRight="2dp"
       android:paddingTop="2dp" >
    </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
          android:layout_margin="2dp"
          android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
          android:layout_row="1"
          android:background="@drawable/titre"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:padding="2dp"
          android:paddingBottom="2dp"
          android:paddingLeft="2dp"
          android:paddingRight="2dp"
          android:paddingTop="2dp" >
    </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_column="0"
          android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
          android:layout_margin="2dp"
          android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
          android:layout_row="2"
          android:background="@drawable/a"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:padding="2dp"
          android:paddingBottom="2dp"
          android:paddingLeft="2dp"
          android:paddingRight="2dp"
          android:paddingTop="2dp" >
    </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
          android:layout_margin="2dp"
          android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
          android:layout_row="2"
          android:background="@drawable/titre"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:padding="2dp"
          android:paddingBottom="2dp"
          android:paddingLeft="2dp"
          android:paddingRight="2dp"
          android:paddingTop="2dp" >
    </LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_column="0"
  android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
  android:layout_margin="2dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
  android:layout_row="3"
  android:background="@drawable/b"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:padding="2dp"
  android:paddingBottom="2dp"
  android:paddingLeft="2dp"
  android:paddingRight="2dp"
  android:paddingTop="2dp" >
    </LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="276dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_column="1"
     android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
     android:layout_margin="2dp"
     android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
     android:layout_row="3"
     android:background="@drawable/titre"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:padding="2dp"
     android:paddingBottom="2dp"
     android:paddingLeft="2dp"
     android:paddingRight="2dp"
     android:paddingTop="2dp" >
    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
  android:layout_margin="2dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
  android:layout_row="3"
  android:background="@drawable/titre"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:padding="2dp"
  android:paddingBottom="2dp"
  android:paddingLeft="2dp"
  android:paddingRight="2dp"
  android:paddingTop="2dp" >
   </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_column="3"
              android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
         android:layout_margin="2dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
         android:layout_row="3"
         android:background="@drawable/titre"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:padding="2dp"
         android:paddingBottom="2dp"
         android:paddingLeft="2dp"
         android:paddingRight="2dp"
         android:paddingTop="2dp" >
    </LinearLayout>
</GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

i use GridLayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a GridLayout, you should use a LinearLayout and use the `android:weightSum` property. This would allow you to structure your layout to that it scales to any device.

You can have something like

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight=".7"
    android:padding="2dp" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.6"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_weight="1.1"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="2" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="181dp"
            android:layout_height="71dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button15"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button16"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button17"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </GridLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".8"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight=".7" >
</LinearLayout>
```

With the following layout, you have three columns, then you can start putting things inside those linear layouts doing the same thing, assign a weightSum to those layout and a weight to the inner layouts.

I can add more content to the example above if you need a more indepth exmaple.

Comment: hi zabawaba yes it's good idea but i don't can create the center layout with this method :(

Comment: Sure you can, the Linear Layout in the middle can have a vertical Linear Layout inside with 3 items. The first can be a GridView to set up the buttons, the second and third would be a linear layout. If you'd like me to provide a more indepth example, I can but it would have to wait a few hours.

Comment: hello
please can you give me the example how I give you with your method because I experiment several times and I have a problem with the middle layout (help me please )

Comment: help me plz juste for the middle layout

Comment: Edit has been added - enjoy!